# Angularjs jQuery datatables add processing event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I use the Angular datatables module. https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables

I try add the `processing.dt` event, but it does not work.

This is the original code from the base api
https://datatables.net/reference/event/processing

```
$('#example')
    .on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
        $('#processingIndicator').css( 'display', processing ? 'block' : 'none' );
    } )
    .dataTable();
```

And this is my unworked code

```
.withOption('processing.dt', function( e, settings, processing){
           console.log(processing);
           $scope.loading = processing;
           }) .withOption('initComplete', function(){
                $scope.loading = false;
           })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in using the dataTables events when dealing with angular datatables. If you have a table

```
<table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" id="example">
```

then this works [ http://plnkr.co/edit/hBDjR9ytD0hK6YgwrgMd?p=preview ]

```
$('#example').on('processing.dt', function() {
   console.log('processiong.dt');
})
```

and this works [ http://plnkr.co/edit/zKYyrneXl2YudNTXZkXv?p=preview ]

```
angular.element('#example').on('processing.dt', function() {
   console.log('processiong.dt');
})
```

If you use a `dtInstance` you can even attach event listeners to that too (here waiting for `dtInstance` to be initialised, then attaching a `order.dt` handler [ http://plnkr.co/edit/DJa1xwzxArrWhplDY278?p=preview ]) :

```
$scope.dtInstance = {}    

$scope.$watch('dtInstance', function() {
    if ($scope.dtInstance.DataTable) {
        $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.on('order.dt', function() {
           console.log('order.dt')
        })
    }
})
```

Just to demonstrate that there is no particular "angular datatables" way of handling events, it is basically the exact same - you just have a few more options since you also have the `angular.element()` way and can work on the special `dtInstance` object.

Comment: angular.element('#cart_activity_table').on('processing.dt', function( e, settings, processing){
                        $scope.loading = processing;
                }); worked